# Texmaker (windows 7) don't use TEXINPUTS environment variable?

Tags: miktex, texmaker

I normally use Unix system, but I am forced for a while on a Windows7 setup. I installed MikTex and texmaker 4.0.4. All is working except it seems that texmaker is not respecting  the `TEXINPUTS` variable.

MWE: go in one dir and create directories `TeXinputs` and `subdir`. In `subdir`, file `testinput.tex`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{null}
\begin{document}
Nothing
\end{document}
```

in directory `TeXinputs` create the file `null.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{null}[2013/11/12 null package.]
\def\called{\relax}
\endinput
```

then add the environment variable as user  `TEXINPUTS` with value `.:../TeXinputs//`.

To add it in Windows, open the "Start" menu, and start typing "environment" in the search box (I suppose it will be different with a non-English installation --- in Spanish should be "variables de entorno"). Then  choose "set environment variables for your account"and, in the windows that opens, you can add all the variables you want. This is my example:

[image: Setting user environment variables]

I have it defined and checked it  (this is from a bash shell installed by git):

```
$echo $TEXINPUTS
./:../TeXinpus//
```

The idea is that I can use a structure like this in my work directory:

```
$ls 
TeXinputs subdir1 subdir2
```

This **works great for MikTeX**, to have common files in the same place. I can compile my files correctly from bash:

```
$ pdflatex testinput
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
("z:\adit\My Documents\test\subdir\testinput.tex"
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("z:\adit\My Documents\test\subdir\..\TeXinputs\\null.sty")
("z:\adit\My Documents\test\subdir\testinput.aux") [1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9
/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] ("z:\adit\My Documents\test\subdir\testinput.aux")
)<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on testinput.pdf (1 page, 12304 bytes).
Transcript written on testinput.log.
```

As you can see, the file `z:\adit\My Documents\test\subdir\..\TeXinputs\\null.sty` is found and all is ok.

**The problem and question**:  opening the file in texmaker and trying to compile gives error --- it can't find the ../TeXinputs/null.sty file.

I checked too:

- setting TEXINPUTS as a "system" environment variable (don't work)
- using absolute path instead of relative one (with or without spces in the path, don't work)

Any hint on why relative TEXINPUTS paths are not working in texmaker?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Texmaker. Remember it just calls latex. AFAIR miktex does not support the texinputs variable. Instead you have to use the miktex setting manager to add an extra root

Comment: @daleif -- no, pdflatex works perfectly from (windows) command line, as stated in the question --- see the example where `../null.sty` is found.  My problem is exactly that pdflatex works but called from texmaker it doesn't.

Comment: I don't suppose TeXmaker reads your environment configuration files. So when you run it in TeXmaker, you have a default environment and the variable is not defined.

Comment: @cfr --- tomorrow I will try to put it on the system variables. Could be that. Thanks. (although every program running as an user should have all the same variables, methinks, but well).

Comment: Well certainly kile, for example, does not pick up everything I set in my environment when I'm using a shell. It probably depends just how and where you set the value. daleif seems to know how to work around this in MikTEX, though.

Comment: Reading the docs miktex seem to comply to `TEXINPUTS` so it would be nice to know how exactly you set that env variable.

Comment: Edit the question and found a partial answer.

Comment: @cfr the Kile problem is probably the fact that the environment variables that you have in the shell in Linux are not the same that you have in the Desktop Environment (unless you set them in ~/.pam_environment file). See http://askubuntu.com/a/356973/16395

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just citing that as evidence that programmes do not, in fact, use all the same variables as in the shell solely because they are running as the relevant user. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution!.

The problem is the colon `:` in the `TEXINPUTS` path, used in Unix to separate the various paths, and that utterly confuses Windows. Instead of the colon, to separate elements in the path you should use a semicolon `;`.

So setting:

```
TEXINPUTS=../TeXinputs
```

as in this image:

[image: setting texinputs]

it then **does** works in texmaker. If you need more than one path, you can use

```
TEXINPUTS=../TeXinputs;C:/Users/MYUSER/Desktop/TeXinputsGlobal
```

...and it works ok.

The confusion was that the `bash` shell understands the notation `/c/` instead of `C:\` but `CMD.exe` doesn't.

Comment: In TeXmaker, Did you try  adding `TEXINPUTS` info at `Options`-->`Configure Texmaker`-->`Add to PATH` ?

Comment: Yes. It didn't work; I think it adds literally to `PATH` variables (which is where the executable are found).

Comment: Found it --- now I'll edit the answer.

Comment: [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/General-Variables.html#fn-1) it is explained why colons cannot be used as path separator in Windows environment variables.