# How to set path in STY file as relative to this file path

Tags: packages, relative

I need to write several documents (`mainBook1.tex`, `mainBook2.tex`,..), all with the same layout. So basically I moved all common settings to outer file (`baseSettings.sty`) extension, which is pleaced in other path from docs main TeX files. See my files tree:

```
 +-Documents
   +-Base
   | +-baseSettings.sty
   | +-BaseImages
   |   +-headerImage.jpg
   |   +-footerImage.jpg
   +-Book1
   | +-mainBook1.tex
   +-Book2
     +-mainBook2.tex
```

`mainBook1.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{../Base/baseSettings}
\begin{document}
...
```

`baseSettings.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{baseSettings}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{margin=2.0cm, bottom=3.5cm, top=2.5cm}
\usepackage{...}
% HEADER AND FOOTER:
\rhead{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{BaseImages/headerImage.jpg}}
\rfoot{\includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{BaseImages/footerImage.jpg}}
...
```

And problem is, that those `.jpg` files cant be found. If I move folder `BaseImages` into `Book1` folder, everything works fine. But I would like to have base images stored only once.

So the question is: How to set those paths in `.sty` file as relative from this file?

I use: MiKTeX with TeXworks. I just press the Typeset button to create PDFs – I'm not familiar wih all the magic behind.

Is it possible to compile it with command?

Comment: Set the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable to ssomething `../Base;../Base/BaseImages;` and then you should be able to use `\usepackage{baseSettings}` and the images will work. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149714/texmaker-windows-7-dont-use-texinputs-environment-variable.

Answer (score 5):

You should *never* use a path with `\usepackage` just use  `\usepackage{baseSettings}` and it's usually more portable to omit the path from `\includegraphics` as well, so `\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{headerImage}` then just arrange that `Base//` is in the tex input path and any files anywhere below that will be found.

```
 TEXINPUTS=Base//: pdflatex mainBook1
```

would work for example if you have a bash or similar command line, but normally you would set the default TEXINPUTS elsewhere.